# How to generate random numbers, strings and select a random choice from a drop down list in Watin?

Tags: watin

I have not been able to find the correct syntax to use in this scenario, can anyone help?

For examples of what I would like to do:

```
ieInUse.TextField(Find.ById("Blah")).TypeText("Zzz");   -- I'd like to replace the 'Zzz' with just a random string.

ieInUse.GoTo("http://randomwebsite/Description/11");  -- Replacing the 11 with a random 2 numbers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do have some opinions on testing with non deterministic data, but I'll keep them to myself as I don't know the background :)

I don't know of any built-in functionality for that, but you can easily add your own methods to do it;

```
    static string RandomString(int len)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.Range(1, len)
            .Select(_ => (char)(random.Next() % 95 + 33)).ToArray());
    }

    static string RandomDigits(int len)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        return new string(Enumerable.Range(1, len)
            .Select(_ => (char) (random.Next()%10 + '0')).ToArray());
    }
```

Then you can just do;

```
ieInUse.TextField(Find.ById("Blah")).TypeText(RandomString(7)); 
ieInUse.GoTo("http://randomwebsite/Description/" + RandomDigits(2));
```

Comment: What are the opinions that you have? I'm quite new to coding automated tests, so any input would be appreciated. :)

Comment: @user1706751 Well, I'll make it brief and say that "fuzzy testing" has its place for finding the odd bug and can be very good for load/security testing, but for unit testing purposes, you really want the tests to test *the same thing all the time*. There is nothing as annoying as tests that fail randomly (ok, even worse, erroneously pass) and you can't repeat the failure every time to fix it. When you use TDD, you really want *100% repeatable* test cases.